# Update column using rows of a table, without using cursor or any other iteration

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

[alt text http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/1797/updatetable.png](http://img248.imageshack.us/img248/1797/updatetable.png)

Update Combined column using CategoryCode of every OrderId. In this example there are two OrderIds 990 and 986. Need to concatenate categories of these two individually.

The desired result is like this.

```
990 Bus, Pub, Shoot, Club, Bus, Hos
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the order of the terms in the comma-separated list important?

Comment: No order is not important. Just need all codes of an order in one string separated by comma.

Comment: Is maximum number 2 as in example or it can be more?

Comment: This is just example there might be 100 or 1000 number of Orders and one order might have 2 to 20 number of child records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE test
SET    combined = Left(j.combined, Len(j.combined) - 1)
FROM   test t
   JOIN (SELECT a.orderid,
                (SELECT categorycode + ','
                 FROM   test b
                 WHERE  b.orderid = a.orderid
                 ORDER  BY orderid
                 FOR XML PATH('')) AS combined
         FROM   test a
         GROUP  BY orderid) AS j
     ON j.orderid = t.orderid
```